# I need helping installing OpenPHT on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, dpkg

I am a new Ubuntu user and I've just started with a fresh install running version Ubuntu 18.04.1. I can't seem to get Openpht to install. Every time I try I just get this error:

[image]

```
(Reading database ... 266350 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openpht_1.8.0.148-573b6d73-xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openpht (1.8.0.148+573b6d73~xenial) over (1.8.0.148+573b6d73~xenial) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openpht:
 openpht depends on libboost-system1.58.0; however:
  Package libboost-system1.58.0 is not installed.
 openpht depends on libboost-thread1.58.0; however:
  Package libboost-thread1.58.0 is not installed.
 openpht depends on libglew1.13 (>= 1.12.0); however:
  Package libglew1.13 is not installed.
 openpht depends on libmicrohttpd10 (>= 0.9.20); however:
  Package libmicrohttpd10 is not installed.
 openpht depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 openpht depends on libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3); however:
  Package libva-x11-1 is not installed.
 openpht depends on libva1 (>= 1.2.0); however:
  Package libva1 is not installed.
 openpht depends on libcec2 | libcec3; however:
  Package libcec2 is not installed.
  Package libcec3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package openpht (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openpht
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Your picture is of text; so please copy & paste it into your question (it's easier to read, and I can copy the packages & look for you - I can't & won't risk typos by trying to perfectly type from a picture).  Also stating your version of Ubuntu is helpful  (I could guess from packages, again if I could copy & paste packages if it'd been text; bionic?)

Comment: I've changed it thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You are running Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) you've now confirmed, but are trying to load a package intended for Xenial (16.04). As a result it wants libraries for xenial (eg. picking one https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libboost-system1.58.0&searchon=names) where you'll note it's available for 16.04 LTS.  Two years have passed between 16.04 (2016.April) & 18.04 (2018.April release) which means API/ABI changes which is why packages have rules to prevent breakage (crashes etc). As a newbie you should stick to programs for your release (and avoid dep-hell)

Comment: Bionic (18.04) uses the 1.62 (not 1.58) version of the package I picked (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libboost-system1&searchon=names) .  If you add (quick dirty fix) the repo needed to solve that issue, it'll cause a lot more .. which is why its commonly called dependency-hell  (a name given by new-users).   The new [ubuntu] user fix is to find a 18.04/Bionic source of whatever program you want that will install and run in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: *I'm not going to look at each package; to see if it clashes with others, and can be freely installed in your 18.04 system; you can if you like; but if you do your homework you can avoid dep-hell by allowing only certain packages; but this is not for 'new-users' in my opinion. I also don't know what openpht does which makes it harder for me...*

Comment: @BenRuckman where you got `openpht` package? I can't find it [in repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=openpht).

Comment: I got it from here https://github.com/RasPlex/OpenPHT/releases

Answer (score 0):

The only way is use the [AppImage version of the latest OpenPHT](https://github.com/DEAKSoftware/OpenPHT-AppImage).

Just download the lastest .AppImage file from here:

https://github.com/DEAKSoftware/OpenPHT-AppImage/releases

Then [make it executable](https://itsfoss.com/use-appimage-linux/#attachment_17444) and run the AppImage file. Just it!

Works on 14.04 and above!

18.04 works like a charm!